# How to redirect back to app in url scheme with Xcode 6.0.1

Tags: ios

I am Working on a app in which there is a Registration field. When Registration is done successfully I get a confirmation mail. When I Confirm the link then I want to navigate back to my app using URL Schemes. How Can I achieve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

1. Go into your app's info.plst file.
2. Add a Row to this and call it "URL types".
3. Expand the first item in "URL types" and add a row called "URL identifier", the value of this string should be the reverse domain for your app e.g. "com.yourcompany.myapp".
4. Again, add a row into the first item in "URL types" and call it "URL Schemes".
5. Inside "URL Schemes" you can use each item as a different URL you wish to use, so if you wanted to use "myapp://" you would create an item called "myapp".

Using the URL scheme, you've now registered the URL with the app. You can start the application by opening a URL with the custom scheme.

Use `UIApplicationDelegate` if you want to provide a custom handler for it. All you need to do is provide an implementation for it in your delegate.

Then get it:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
  if (!url) { 
    return NO; 
  } 
  // Do something with the url here 
}
```

Refer to [this](http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html).

Answer (score 2):

In the project target, go to the Info tab and add a `URL types` in the URL Schemes field - let's say "myApp".
Then, the email should contain a link like: `myApp://something` and your app will be launched.
Best practice would require that you actually check that "something" and show the user a "confirmation" message.

Comment: You mean to say I have to add the link of the url which gives the mail on registration button click?

Comment: To launch the app you have to add the same URL type (scheme) in the email. So if you have "myApp" in the Xcode project, you should have "myApp://" in the email. When the user will tap on the link, your app will be launched. ps. Keep in mind that sometimes this link won't work, if, for example, the user opens the email inside Chrome or a different email client.

Comment: After you've added the URL Scheme and ran the app once, you can also open the app by calling "myApp://" in MobileSafari (on either the device or simulator) to test that the app gets opened.

Comment: Will you make me clear on this. Suppose I am getting mail from www.myapp.com and i have added myapp in the plist file. what do you mean by   "myApp://" in the email. I am not getting this correctly. Please Explain. Thanks.

Comment: To launch the app, once you've added the "myApp" URL scheme, you need a link in the email like this: `myApp://something` (instead of http:// - which would open a browser, you use myApp:// to open your app)